# How do I save a scipy distribution in a list or array to call?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

I'm building a small project for fun, and am having trouble saving a distribution that I need to print. I'm using scipy to create the distribution but can't find a way to save it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

def normal_distro_build(mean, standard_dev,students, grades):

grades = []

mean = 73
standard_dev = 10
students = 23


# creates the boundries of the distrobution

a,b = ((0 - mean) / standard_dev),((100 - mean)/standard_dev)

loc = mean

scale = standard_dev

# creates a truncated normal distrobution using the inputs

normal_distro =  truncnorm( a , b , loc , scale ).rvs(students)

grades.append(normal_distro)

print(grades[0])
```

Comment: Not really clear what the problem is. It seems `normal_distro` is your distribution, which is a numpy array. So you would save it using numpy.

Comment: Sorry I'm still getting used to numpy and matplotlib. It saved at a numpy array no problem. Thank you for your help!